# Moving Between Rooms in PyCharm

Tags: python

Trying to get Python to move between rooms in a text based game. No matter what direction, it will not move out of the bathroom. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: `command in current_room` should probably be rewritten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
choices = rooms[current_room]

if command in choices:
    current_room = choices[command]
else:
    print("You cannot go in that direction.")
```